# Set PHP cron job on windows server 2003

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks, cron

I am using Windows server 2003, IIS6, php and mysql. I have a problem setting the cronjob using built in schedule task feature in Windows OS.

- Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Schedule Tasks
- Add "new schedule task"
- It asks me choose programs. Should I choose php.exe or internet explorer, because php files run on internet browser right? How do I call the specific php files (assume the name of the file is cronjob.php)

I need your guys help. Please advise.

Answer (score 11):

if you would like to run the scheduled task every minute you have to set it up through the command like as follows:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "my task" /tr "C:\Program Files\php5\php.exe c:\wwwroot\inetpub\website\myfile.php?task=fetch"
```

This will let you run the task each minute. There is no way to do this through to the task scheduler gui to my knowledge so I just wanted to share this solution.

Comment: If we want to run job every 8 days, the command will be: schtasks /create /sc daily /mo 8 ... You can see MS's technet page for detail: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_days

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to call php.exe as the interpreter with the path to the script as its argument, example:

```
"c:\program files\php5\php.exe" c:\cronscripts\cronjob.php
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make run every 2 minutes? Cuz I want to do a testing first. So far it asked me daily,monthly or specify the day, but I cant afford to wait for that long to do the test LOL. You get what I mean?

Comment: Yep, no idea though, there should be an option to do it I would have thought. You could just call the script using the command line every two minutes just like above, though. Might be easier, then you can generate more results in 2 minutes' time than 1...

Answer (score 2):

You call

```
php.exe cronjob.php
```