# PHP cronjob on Windows with parameter and pipe

Tags: php, windows, cron, scheduling

I want to run a PHP file via Task Scheduler on Windows.
Everything runs except a parameter comes in.

**This runs:**

> cmd /C C:\php\php.exe
>   "C:\cron\cronrun.php" >>
>   "C:\cron\log\cronrun.log" 2>&1

**This is not running:**

> cmd /C C:\php\php.exe
>   "C:\cron\cronrun.php" --run >>
>   "C:\cron\log\cronrun.log" 2>&1

How can I run a job which includes an argument?

Thanks for help.
-lony

Sources:

- [Set PHP cron job on windows server 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323477/set-php-cron-job-on-windows-server-2003)
- http://richarddingwall.name/2009/01/26/capture-the-output-from-a-scheduled-task/

Comment: I don't think the Windows command prompt supports that syntax, does it?

Comment: Did you try the argument without the dashes? "run" instead of "--run"?

Comment: @Mark The command `cmd /C C:\php\php.exe "C:\cron\cronrun.php" "--run" >>  "C:\cron\log\cronrun.log" 2>&1` runs fine and log says "cronrun.job" (cmd)
 Finished 1/19/2011 4:08:05 PM
 Result: The task completed with an exit code of (0). but there is no result!

Comment: What result are you expecting? What result do you get without the argument?

Comment: I want everything piped to the log file and some emails send through the cron job, but either the log nor the emails are filled/sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `--` before the `--run` like this:

```
cmd /C C:\php\php.exe "C:\cron\cronrun.php" -- --run >> "C:\cron\log\cronrun.log" 2>&1
```

The clue is in the usage message:

```
$ php --help
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]

...

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin
```